# Can I extract the database from android application?

Tags: sqlite

Can I copy the database file from an android application is it possible?
Can anyone please suggest me how can I achieve that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can, for this you will need Android Studio
Steps are as follows:

1. Connect your debugging device.
2. Open Device file explore which is there in Android Studio (bottom right)
3. Browse data->data>(your apps package name)->databases
4. Right click and save it to on your machine

Comment: @Shiva_Kishore i am glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can but you can do it only in the debuggable app not in release app or other apps